# Transformation of magnetic field under an isometry of space

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vectors, vector-fields, linear-algebra

**THE PROBLEM**

Suppose we are in stationary conditions, in which case the following Maxwell Equations hold:
$$
\underline{\nabla} \cdot \underline{B} \equiv 0 \\
\underline{\nabla} \times \underline{B} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \underline{J}
$$
Let $\phi(\underline{x}):=R\underline{x} + \underline{a}$ be an isometry of $\Bbb R^3$ (i.e. $R$ is ortohogonal) and suppose that all the current lies in a bounded domain (so that we can have zero boundary conditions at infinity).

I would like to prove tha following claim:

> The magnetic field $\underline{B}'$ generated by the current density $\underline{J}'(\underline{x}) := R\underline{J}(\phi^{-1}(\underline{x}))$ (which is the result of the so called "active transformation" of the source under the isometry) is given by:
> $$
> \underline{B}'(\underline{x}) = \det(R)R\underline{B}(\phi^{-1}(\underline{x})) \hspace{5mm} (1)
> $$

---

**MY ATTEMPT**

My idea is to use the uniqueness theorem for the magnetic field with zero boundary condition at infinity. Therefore, if I can show that (1) satisfies Maxwell's Equations I would be done. I have already verified the first equation but I have not been able to verify the second because I get stuck at:

$$[\underline{\nabla} \times \underline{B}(\underline{x})]_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \det(R) R_{km} R_{jl} \partial_l B_m(\psi^{-1}(\underline{x}))$$

---

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use
$$
\epsilon_{ijk}R_{ai}R_{bj}R_{ck}= \epsilon_{abc} {\rm det}(R)
$$
to show that $\nabla \times {\bf B}$ transforms as a 3-(pseudo?)-vector under ${\rm O}(3)$?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Could you point me at a proof of this fact?

Comment: $\epsilon_{ijk}R_{1i}R_{2j}R_{3k}$ is the definbition of ${\rm det}(R))$ and the extra $\epsilon_{abc}$ comes from the antisymmmetry of the determinant under interchanging colums.

Comment: Thank you very much!